# Show that X and Y are conditionally independent given Z

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Let X,Y denote the number of heads in the first and last two flips separately, and Z be the indicator random variable of the second flip. Given a fair coin and independently flip it three times.

\begin{equation}
    X =
      \begin{cases}
         0 & \text{if there are no heads in the first two flips}\\
         1 & \text{if there is exactly one head in the first two flips}\\
         2 & \text{if there is exactly two heads in the first two flips}
      \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    Y =
      \begin{cases}
         0 & \text{if there are no heads in the last two flips}\\
         1 & \text{if there is exactly one head in the last two flips}\\
         2 & \text{if there is exactly two heads in the last two flips}
      \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    Z =
      \begin{cases}
         1 & \text{if the second flip is H}\\
         0 & \text{if the second flip is T}\\
      \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Show that, X is not independent to Y, but X and Y are conditionally independent given Z.

My attempt:

To show that X is not independent to Y is easy. We can take the case where $\{x,y\}=\{0,0\}$. Then we have that
$$\mathbb{P}(X=0)\cdot\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{16}\neq\frac{1}{8}=\mathbb{P}(X\cap Y)$$

To prove that X and Y are conditionally independent given Z, I was thinking that we need to show that $\mathbb{P}(X=x|Z=z)\mathbb{P}(Y=y|Z=z)=\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y|Z=z)$ is true for all combinations of x,y,z. However, this would result in showing the equality is true $3\cdot3\cdot2=18$ times, which seems like a lot of work. Is there a more efficient way of showing this independence? Thank you.

Comment: How many flips are there in total? $3$?

Comment: Yes 3 flips in total

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** When given the count for heads in the middle coin, the count for heads in the first and last two coins are *each* determined by the count for heads in the first and last coin, respectively, -- which are independent.

Let $U$ and $V$ be these counts, and so we have: $X=U+Z$ and $Y=V+Z$.

Thus $U,V,Z\overset{iid}\sim\mathcal U[0,1]$ and taking any $i,j,k$ from $\{0,1\}$, you may show: $$\mathsf P(X{=}i{+}k, Y{=}j{+}k\mid Z{=}k)=\mathsf P(X{=}i{+}k\mid Z{=}k)\mathsf P(Y{=}j{+}k\mid Z{=}k)$$

Answer (score 1):

```
        X     Y     Z
H H H   [2    2]    1
H H T   [2    1]    1
H T H   1     1     0
H T T   1     0     0
T H H   [1    2]    1
T H T   [1    1]    1
T T H   0     1     0
T T T   0     0     0
```

You don't need to show it 18 times. You can just show it 8 times. Start with Z=1.

$$P(X=2|Y=1)=P(X=2|Y=2)=P(X=2)=\frac 1 2\\
P(X=1|Y=2)=P(X=1|Y=1)=P(X=1)=\frac 1 2$$

Now do it once more for the case Z=0 and you're done. (This uses an equivalent definition of independence that $P(A|B)=P(A)$ means that A and B are independent.)